# open and plot several data file on same plot Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Newbie here, first question.

I have several data files, that I want to open, get the relevant data (x and y) and plot **on the same plot**.
I know how to do it if I type out a plot statement for each of them, but what I would want to create is a single function or script that takes the filenames as input, extracts the data (this part depends on the type of file, but I think I know how to do it) and then creates one single plot with the different datasets. It should be pretty basic, but all my attempts return a plot for each file.

I think that my problem is that I have not understood how the whole ax, fig, gca, plot loop works, as I have been learning mostly by adapting things and doing.

So far I have created a for loop that opens each file, gets the data and stores it in a dataframe (a dataframe per file) then uses a plt.plot to plot, and then out of the loop, I have a plt.gca() that in my intentions would get things together to then modify the plot, add stuff to it and save it. I have also tried changing the position of the gca and using ax and fig, playing around with a few tutorials, but never with satisfying results.

I get different kinds of errors, depending on the different iterations of the script, here is one of my attempts. If there's an electrochemist among you they might recognize the datatype :) but the datatype should not be important.

**EDIT: I modified the script, as it had a couple of errors, the current versions returns an empty plot. 
**
the current version returns an empty plot, the dataframe is created properly, from what I can see

```
files = ['file1.i2b', 'file2.i2b']
colors = []
fig_name = ''
file_type = 'i2b'
norm = []

if len(colors) != len(files):    
    l = len(files)    
    col_list = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']
    color_list = col_list[0:l]
if len(norm)!= len(files):
        norm = [1]*len(files)
if file_type == 'i2b':
    for filename, norm_factor, col in zip (files, norm, color_list):    
        flnm1 = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        data_xrd = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=(' '), decimal = '.', skiprows =10,
                       header= None, names =['Freq','Real_part', 'Imm_part'])
        data_xrd['norm_Imm_part'] =  (0-data_xrd['Imm_part'])*norm_factor
        data_xrd['norm_Re_part'] = data_xrd['Real_part']*norm_factor
        plt.plot(x=data_xrd['norm_Re_part'], y=data_xrd['norm_Imm_part'], 
                 legend=flnm1, style='-', color = col)
        #plt.show

plt.gca()
#plt.axhline(y=0, color='k', linestyle='--')
#plt.set_xlabel('Z_real [Ohm]')
#plt.set_ylabel('Z_imm [Ohm]')
#plt.set_aspect('equal')
plt.savefig(fig_name + '.png')
```

Now, it might be better to split the data extraction to a different function, so that the plotting function is more flexible and can be paired with different kinds of data input, but at the moment I'd just like to understand how to use plot multiple files on a single plot simply by using a list of their names as input, in order to facilitate the grouping and plotting of a lot of datafiles.

Thanks for the help and please let me know how to improve my question!

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I realized there's errors in what I copy pasted, I'll fix them.
Mostly, I get individual plots instead of a single one